# Jasper Report shows message "The Report is empty"

Tags: jasper-reports

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“The Report is empty” - is bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534141/the-report-is-empty-is-bug)

I created iReport which execute stor proc in MS SQL server with 3 input parameters: startdate, enddate and dept_nm. In Jasper server repository I've created 3 controls with the same names. Using iReport the report i created works fine - no issues.
After I exported this report to Jasper Server and when prompt pop-ps asking to enter valid parameters - I entered valid dates and dept_nm but screen shows in the middle message "The report is empty". What is the possible problem?

Thank you.

Comment: have you tried using SQL Profiler to run a trace to see if any data is returned?

Comment: Data is returnde fine in SQL server, in iReport - it doesn't only under web JasperReports Server.